# В Python добавить элементы списка

Tags: python, алгоритм, list, математика

Решаю задачу, в рамках которой пытаюсь заполнить новый список `param_list`. Логика формирования его элементов представлена ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате же реализации моего кода в список добавляется лишь первый элемент `poly_0 = x_j - x_col_list[0]`. Он равен `0.157 - 0 = 0`

Что не так в коде?

Код:

```
params_list = []
x_j = 0.157
x_col_list = [0.0, 0.3142, 0.6283]

for args in range(order):   # args = 0,1,2
    poly_0 = x_j - x_col_list[0]
    if not args:
        params_list.append(poly_0)
    poly_n =  (x_j - x_col_list[args])
    if not args:
        param_list.append(poly_n)
        poly_0 = poly_n

print(params_list)
```

Comment: `range(order)` что такое `order`? 11 строчка `param_list` вместо `params_list`. `if not args` дважды проверка хотя переменная после 1 никак не меняется, В общем не понятно что делает ваш код

Comment: В задаче просили вывести накопительные произведения, а вы выводите только отдельные множители.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо писать условные операторы. Ищите общий случай, а не подбирайте исключения.

`product` накапливает текущее произведение. `x_i` пробегает значения из `x_col_list`. `params_list` - хранит результат - накопленные произведения:

```
x_j = 0.157
x_col_list = [0.0, 0.3142, 0.6283]

params_list = []
product = 1
for x_i in x_col_list:
    product *= x_j - x_i
    params_list.append(product)

print(params_list)
```

> ```
> $ python temp.py
> [0.157, -0.024680399999999998, 0.011631872519999998]
> ```

Можно вовсе обойтись без цикла. [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) вычисляет последовательные произведения:

```
import itertools
import operator


x_j = 0.157
x_col_list = [0.0, 0.3142, 0.6283]

params_list = list(itertools.accumulate(
    (x_j - x_i for x_i in x_col_list),
    operator.mul
))

print(params_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас две ошибки в:

```
 if not args:
        param_list.append(poly_n)
```

Надо:

```
 if args:
        params_list.append(poly_n)
```

Кроме того, `order` "вручную" на 3 выставить пришлось.

Полный код, работающий у меня - ниже.
На выходе: [0.157, -0.15719999999999998, -0.47129999999999994]

```
params_list = []
x_j = 0.157
x_col_list = [0.0, 0.3142, 0.6283]

for args in range(3):   # args = 0,1,2
    poly_0 = x_j - x_col_list[0]
    if not args:
        params_list.append(poly_0)
    poly_n =  (x_j - x_col_list[args])
    if args:
        params_list.append(poly_n)
        poly_0 = poly_n

print(params_list)
```

Comment: зачем в ручную, если по идее должно быть len(x_col_list)

Comment: @Сергей, исправил, убрав `not`. Пока почему-то получаю так же только 0.157

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, Вы правы. Просто у меня `order` ранее в коде обозначен. Его задает пользователь. Хотя действительно можно и Вашим методом

Comment: Я убрал `not` и добавил s, заменил order на 3  получил: [0.157, -0.15719999999999998, -0.47129999999999994]. Код включаю в ответ.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, я оставил это (order) на усмотрение автора кода. Я просто решал задачу, поставленную автором.

Comment: Заметьте что оба условных оператора делают одно и то же действие.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, я не проводил инспекцию кода.  Автора интересовало, почему элемент не добавляется, я это и проверял. Но да, "Что не так в коде?" можно рассмотреть и расширенно:-)